# Exit vim if last buffer is closed which is not buftype=nofile or buftype=quickfix

Tags: vim

Open up an instance of vim, and execute the following commands:

```
:help
:wincmd w
:quit
```

Vim will exit, even though the help buffer is still open.  How can one get this functionality for the location-list?

Vim also exhibits the same behavior if the one is using a `preview-window`.

```
:pedit $MYVIMRC
:quit
```

It would be nice get this behavior for other buffers, such as if using the Calendar plugin, and you closed your last buffer.

Comment: You can't open the location list window if there's no location list so what is your first question? Did you confuse it with the error list window? The help window is readonly while the others are not, hence the difference in behavior, I presume.

Comment: No confusion. Location-list has buftype=quickfix

Comment: Confusion: you can do `:copen` without defining an error list but you can't do `:lopen` without a location list. So you can't do with the location list what you did with `:help` in your first example.

Answer (score 1):

Setup a QuitPre autocommand for that specific buffer (or ask the author of such a plugin to
automatically setup such an autocommand). For your use case with the quickfix buffer, you can possibly do this:

```
au QuitPre * exe "lclose|cclose"
```